# Как выровнять ul по центру?

Tags: html, css

```css
.box_block {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
.box_block li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
.box_div {
  width: 1150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wa box_div">
  <ul class="box_block">
    <li>
      <img src="/images/box_1.png" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="/images/box_2.png" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="/images/box_3.png" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Но не выравнивается по центру. Что делать?

Comment: Из вопроса непонятно - вам нужно `ul` выровнять по центру `.box_div` или `li` внутри `ul`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<li>` - это [блочный элемент](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements). От того, что вы укажете ему обтекание (float), строчным он не станет, а значит и text-align на него действовать не будет.
Вот с такими стилями будет работать так, как вы ожидаете:

```css
.box_block {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.box_block li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

.box_div {
  width: 1150px;
  background: #c0ffee;
}
```

```html
<div class="wa box_div">
  <ul class="box_block">
    <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```